# Interpreting soil test instructions

Tags: fertilizer, soil-amendment, soil-test

I tested my vegetable garden soil with a *lusterleaf rapitest Soil Test Kit.*  My soil test came back as depleted for nitrogen and phosphorous, and adequate for potash.  This is the section of the test kit insert with instructions.

[image]

Am I interpreting these soil results correctly?  It looks like I need to add...

- 36 oz. per 100 sq. ft. of dried blood (6.75 lbs for my garden, which is 300 sq. ft.)
- 27 oz. per 100 sq. ft. of bone meal (5 lbs. for 300 sq. ft.)
- 2.25 to 2.5 oz. per 100 sq. ft. of muriate of potash (1/2 lb. for 300 sq. ft.)

I only ask because adding an egregiously wrong amount would be very difficult to correct!

Also, relatedly, I should choose *either* dried blood *or* nitrate of soda for nitrogen, and not both, right?  It just gives two options?

Comment: Where are you in the world? If in the US, I STRONGLY recommend using your state's University Extension system for any soil testing - they would NEVER recommend dried blood, which will leach out of the soil very quickly.

Comment: US - I used my university extension last year actually,  and they also recommended dried blood for nitrogen.   Is there a better source?

Comment: Where are the actual numbers for your soil? I'm not sure how you determined that your soil is "depleted".

Comment: The test kit gives only four levels, sufficient, adequate,, deficient,  depleted

Comment: I see values for all four categories, but I don't see the actual values from your test. I would've expected a check mark or number value for, say, Nitrogen, and then a recommendation for how to rectify that. Where in the US do you live?